# How to send the data from angular application to flutter application ? I am passing string parameter in url but unable to receive the data in flutter

Tags: angular, flutter, flutter-web

```
1. Below is code for angular
```

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent {
    title = 'web-app';
    onNavigate(){
    const url = 'http://localhost:61097/#/plants/garden ?InputParameter1=" + Value1 +"';
    window.open(url, '_blank');   
    }
    }
```

2. Code for flutter

```
  void get() {
    final Map<String, String> params = Uri.parse(html.window.location.href).queryParameters;
    String? data = params["InputParameter"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `InputParameter1` and `InputParameter`. They must have the same name.

You can debug this by inspecting the `params` Map. Either by debugging or printing it.